# Angular - Update Accordion with results

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to update an accordion from a search that returns an array. On the first load, the full set of results are correctly shown from a service. However, when I search I get the correct values in the console but even with ngModel it is not being updated. Any suggestions?

```
// Snippet of accordion
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
  <ngb-panel [(ngModel)]="modelData" ngDefaultControl *ngFor="let miller of dataService.data.millers; let millerIndex = index" title="{{ miller.name }} - {{ miller.address }}">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      <p>Name: {{ miller.name }}</p>
      <p>Address: {{ miller.address }}</p>
      <p>
        <strong>{{ miller.name }}'s Farms</strong>
      </p>

search(farmName: string, millerName: string) {
  // service being called and snippet of mapping
  const x = this.dataService.data.millers.map(miller => {
  this.modelData = x;
  // Correctly logs results
  console.log(this.modelData);
}
```

Comment: what is `x` inside `map()` function?

Comment: Loops through and returns values if there's a match via name which it correctly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model with ngModel is probably useless since you iterate over your service to display your data.

You simply need to correctly update your data from your service directly, or change the iteration of the ngFor on your modelData used in your component.

The second option is recommended.

Comment: Been looking at this for a while, could you give me an example please Alex. Thanks